# Vim: status in command line

Tags: vim

When I open a file in Vim, a text appears in command line
    "filename" 99L, 9999C
The text disappears when I hit PgDn for example, and then I have an empty command line.

How can I summon that text again, and how can I customize it, say add cursor position?

Note, I am aware of status line and it's not what I'm after.

Comment: `Ctrl+g` will give you filename and line count, and `g Ctrl+g` gives you current position in terms of total column/line/word/byte count. Do you need more file info?

Comment: Daniel, thanks, that's all the info I need at the moment. I looked up help and it seems the output of these is not customizable?

Comment: nameanyone, actually yes it is customizable.  Specifically look at "set statusline".   Also, you may want to use "set laststatus=2" to keep the file and location info. visable.

Comment: @pottsdl, I don't see how I can use statusline to control the output of `Ctrl-G`. I think they are two completely different things. There is `shortmess` that can be used to make the message shorter, but I didn't find how to customize it completely.

Comment: @nameanyone  Sorry, I made a slight mistake.  If you use the statusline, it will allow you to customize and keep it up "permanently" (really regardless of the number of files you have open).

Although in noticing my mistake, there is a "rulerformat" option that allows for customizing the "ruler" talked about by Diogo Rocha and Anthem below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `:set ruler` to make this change stick (same output as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>). Put that in your .vimrc to make it stick across sessions.

Comment: In my Vim, `:set ruler` and `Ctrl-G` produce different output. The combination of having "set ruler" in .vimrc and using `Ctrl-G` when required answers my needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use ' :e ' as command it will display the line again like you would reopen the file you are
currently working in.